# How to select a <div> block inside a text?

Tags: javascript, search

I have a text composed of two `<div>` inside one `<body>` saved as `raw_text` as following:

```
var raw_text = "<body><div>This is the 'div' text that I don't want.</div> <div>This is the 'div' text that I want to print.</div></body>";
```

I need a script for print on the screen only the `<div>` present in raw-text that include a certain string.

if the string wanted is:

```
var x = "that I want";
```

the script should take:

```
<div>This is the 'div' text that I want to print.</div>
```

and the output should be:

```
This is the 'div' text that I want to print.
```

Comment: show your current code/script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it:

1. Use a DOM parser
2. Iterate the text nodes
3. Check if they contain the desired string

```js
var html = "<body><div>This is the 'div' text that I don't want.</div> <div>This is the 'div' text that I want to print.</div></body>";
var x = "that I want";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
var it = doc.createNodeIterator(doc.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
var node;
while (node = it.nextNode()) if(node.nodeValue.includes(x)) {
  console.log(node.nodeValue);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var raw_text = "<body><div>This is the 'div' text that I don't want.</div> <div>This is the 'div' text that I want to print.</div></body>";
var x = "that I want";
var homework_solution = raw_text.match(new RegExp("<div>([^<>]*?"+x+"[^<>]*?)</div>"))[1];
```

This should do the job. The regex could possibly be made a bit more robust.

The "proper" way to do this would be to use DOMParser to search for the node you want.

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). Your last sentence should be in bold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to convert your string to proper DOM elements, and then parse them easily, as @Retr0spectrum says on their comment. You have the HTML in a plain string:

```
var htmlString = "<body><div>This is the 'div' text that I don't want.</div> <div>This is the 'div' text that I want to print.</div></body>";
```

Now you have to:

1. parse it to DOM,
2. filter the elements, and
3. get the text

Like this:

```
// Process the string through jQuery so it parses the DOM elements
var dom = $(htmlString);

// and then we convert to array...
var array = dom.toArray();

// ... so we can filter it, using RegEx to find the
// <div>(s) we are interested in: 
var matchingDivs = array.filter(function (div, i) {
  return $(div).text().match(/that I want/g) !== null;
});

// we pop the last matched div from the filtered array (the first 
// one would also work, since normally you will find just one)
var theDiv = matchingDivs.pop(); 

// Then get the <div>'s text:
var theText = selectedDiv.textContent;
```

The beautiful thing is you can chain all the methods so you can write the above like this:

```
var theText = $(htmlString).toArray().filter(function (div, i) {
  return $(div).text().match(/that I want/g) !== null;
})[0].textContent;
```

**Note:** In the chained methods example I took the first element instead of the last one, using the bracket operator `[0]` instead of `pop()`.

Hope this helps understanding how it works.